# how to make a button open from 3 pm to 9 pm?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to create a button that is active only at this time and in the remaining hours have another image
I tried with NSDate but I do not know which method to use to set this time
is it possible?
what is the code?

Comment: Simplest is probably an NSTimer set up to trigger at the next on or off time.  But there are a half-dozen different ways to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to choose some event, when you are going to check for the date. Let's say, you set up `NSTimer` fo 1 minute interval. Then periodically:

1. Get **current date** & time representation:

   ```
   NSDate *now = [NSDate date];
   ```
2. **Get the hour** using `NSCalendar`:

   ```
   NSDateComponents *components = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSHourCalendarUnit
                                                                  fromDate:now];
   NSUInteger hour = components.hour;
   ```
3. **Compare and apply** availability:

   ```
   BOOL available = (hour >= 3 && hour < 9);
   button.enabled = available;
   ```

I guess you will need to make some adjustments, because of 12/24-hour time.

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing what your environment is makes it hard to say, but I would expect you would need some sort of timer to signal when to activate and deactivate the button.

Ideally, something that will send an event to your code at 3pm (which TZ btw?) and then at 9pm, but possibly a regular once a minute trigger that you can then check actual ToD.

HtH, Ruth

Comment: from this app people can register for the events, and I want the button with which it is active only record at a particular time (3 pm - 9 pm) ...

Answer (score 0):

it is possible.

There are some ways to solve this problem
First, you can use UILocalNotification with setting the fire date.

Second, in another thread, check time permenently. When time is between 3-9pm, 
call postNotification with NSNotificationCenter.

Third, customize your button, then add a timer in custom button.

Answer (score 0):

You can do following,
1) When u start the app check what time is it.
2) if its between 3 pm to 9pm, make the button active, also start a NSTIMER for the end time appropriate
3) if not, set the button image as ur image, make the button inactive, start NSTIMER to be triggered at 3PM
4) When nstimer is triggered , change the image and make it active.

Comment: from this app people can register for the events, and I want the button with which it is active only record at a particular time (3 pm - 9 pm) ...

Comment: 2) if its between 3 pm to 9pm, make the button active, start a NSTimer Also for the end time appropriate
...
what is the code?

Comment: U should try to google it. Would be pretty simple to discover.
Here u go
NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.5
                 target: self
                 selector: @selector(methodName:)
                 userInfo: nil
                 repeats: YES];

Comment: and u can use button.enabled = YES/NO .